# Data and Time representation by Joda Time

Tags: java, android, jodatime

The task is to reformat date time string. Here is an example of an input 2015-11-02T15:53:28+03:00  and desired output format is 2015.11.02 15:53. So there is what I tried

```
DateTime ldt = new DateTime(timeStamp);
DateTimeFormatter outFotmat = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm");
return outFotmat.print(ldt);
```

The format is Ok, but instead 2015.11.02 **15:53** I got 2015.11.02 **12:53** TimeZone shift is missed.

If reguest a time zone like ldt.getZone() it returns correct string "Europe/Moscow"

How to make Joda Time return date and time takin in account time zone?

Comment: Did you try to add the timezone specifier in the format?

Comment: For example like `DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm").withLocale(new Locale("ru","RU"))`.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that I use "Joda-Time library with Android specialization", so there must be a call to init() method.